# Number of eigenfunctions for kernel

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick

While studying machine learning, I've read the following statement:

> The kernel $K(x,y)=(x\cdot y+1)^d$ , for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^p$, has $M={p+d \choose d}$ eigenfunctions that span the space of polynomials in $\mathbb{R}^p$ of total degree $d$.

I do not understand how does the $M={p+d \choose d}$ come from? What does exactly the degree $d$ mean here?

Comment: @mpiktas Sorry, simultaneous edit :-|

Comment: @bit-question, I've latexified your question, but it is clear that definition for $K$ is wrong. What is $(x,y)$?

Comment: @mbq, $(x|y)$ is physics notation for scalar product?

Comment: @mpiktas Rather $\langle x\mid y\rangle$... I thought this is the math one (-;

Comment: @mbq, I'll revert to my version and change definition of $K$, since you left some of the gramatical errors :p :)

Comment: @mpiktas O`right, but I have corrected eigenfunctions.

Comment: @mbq, I've checked the notation of scalar product in wikipedia

Comment: @GaBorgulya, sorry I've rejected your edit, your edit came in the middle of edit-war between me and mbq :) Your effort is very welcome and appreciated.

Comment: @bit-question, is this exact citation? Could you please give a reference?

Comment: You must mean either "of total degree *at most* d" or else you need to use $p+1$ in place of $p$ and mean "*homogeneous* of degree d."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The polynomial kernel $K(x,y) = (x \cdot y + 1)^d$ is easily represented in terms of monomials. The degree $d$ is the maximum degree of the polynomial computed by the kernel and therefore also the maximum degree of any contained monomial.

The problem of determining the number of monomials of degree *exactly* $d$ in $p$ input variables is the same as the problem of finding the number of combinations to draw $d$ elements from a bin with $p$ different elements. The number of such [$d$-combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Example_of_counting_multicombinations) is

$$\left(\!\!{d \choose p}\!\!\right) = {d + p - 1 \choose d} = {d + p - 1 \choose p - 1}.$$

However, we need to consider all monomials of degree $k = 0, \ldots, d$. Using $\sum_{j=k}^{n}{j \choose k} = {n+1 \choose k+1}$ we get

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{d}{p - 1 + k \choose p - 1} = \sum_{k=(p-1)}^{(p-1)+d}{k \choose p - 1} = {p + d \choose p} = {p + d \choose d}.$$

**Addendum**: This formula also nicely showcases the power of kernel functions: Just consider the case where $p = 256$ and $d = 2$. The kernel calculates the scalar product of two vectors (representing the scalar in front of each monomial base function) in a space with dimension ${d + p \choose d} = {256 + 2 \choose 2} = 33153$. An explicit scalar product computation thus involves 33153 multiplications and additions, while the kernel needs $p + d - 1 = 257$ multiplications and $p = 256$ additions.

Answer (score 3):

Take a simple example, if $x,z \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and $d=2$, then,

$$ (\left< x , z \right> + 1)^2 = (x_1z_1 + x_2z_2 + 1)^2 $$
$$ = x_1^2z_1^2 + x_2^2z_2^2 + 2x_1z_1x_2z_2 +x_1z_1 + x_2z_2 + 1$$
$$ = \left< (x_1^2, x_2^2, \sqrt{2}x_1x_2, x_1, x_2, 1), (z_1^2, z_2^2, \sqrt{2}z_1z_2, z_1, z_2, 1) \right> $$
$$ = \left< \phi(\bf{x}), \phi(\bf{z}) \right> $$

where $\phi(\cdot)$ is the feature map, which we can see has 6 eigenfunctions. In this case $p=2$ and $d=2$, so there should be $\left( \begin{array}{c} 4 \\ 2 \end{array} \right) = 6$ eigenfunctions, as predicted. This is trivial but laborious to show for higher dimensions or higher polynomial degree orders.